# Get list of Firebase notifications?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to see all the notifications sent via Firebase?

I can't find anything in the docs or anywhere else.

It'd be cool if it is possible over the console, but HTTP would do as well! Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no available API as of the moment to retrieve your GCM/FCM logs. However, there's been a recent improvement in the Firebase Notifications console where stats (sent count only for now) for messages sent using the FCM API is included in the Firebase Notification console stats. From my answer in the [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40340076/4625829):

> As of August 2018, stats for messages sent using the FCM API are now visible from the console. From the *Cloud Messaging* section, click on the *Reports* tab. From there, you will be able to filter by message type (`notification`, `data`, and all)
>
> [image]
>
> It would seem that the *Impressions* and *Opens* are still only available for messages sent using the console. But *Sends* for sure now counts the messages sent using the FCM API.
>
> Reference: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/in-app-messaging-crashlytics.html

<s>As you might already know, only notifications sent via the console are visible in the [Firebase Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaWEq.png) itself. In the left-side panel, just select on the *Notifications* and you will see the list of Notifications sent using the console.</s>

One approach is also to make use of the Google Play Developer Console, but the app should at least be in Alpha Testing.

Kinda similar posts:

- [Firebase Cloud Messaging Statistics API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40124672/4625829)
- [Firebase notification records/log API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40340076/4625829)

Comment: When I send a POST request to publish a notification (a.k.a message) then I get a `message_id` and a `multicast_id`. Is there any use for those then?

Comment: @Maverick283 For the `multicast_id`, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24865232/4625829). For the `message_id`, it can be used in the [Diagnostics tool](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en).