# Fetch history of sent push notifications from Firebase, in iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an iOS app that integrated with Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notifications from. I know that Firebase saves history of all sent notifications.
Is there a way for each specific device running the app to fetch its own history of sent notifications? I need to do it on client side, not on server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no API to retrieve details of all the sent notifications with FCM (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40341195/4625829) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40525232/4625829)).

The idea is still feasible, however, you'll have to store the logs/history on your own, in your App Server. From there, you could setup your app to retrieve the details that only correspond to the device.